# ojdbc jar version & DataStoreHelper class in websphere application server 7.x for Oracle 12c

Tags: java-7, oracle12c, websphere-7

I am working with JDK 7 and Oracle 12c.

In Websphere application server 7.x version,

**JDBC provider configurations:**

Which version of ojdbc jar i can keep in classpath to support oracle 12c?

**DataSource configurations:**

Whcih Oracle DataStorehelper class can be kept?

Answer (score 1):

According to the following [oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03), you should be using ojdbc7.jar for Oracle 12c

Regarding data store helpers, the latest available one ought to work based on forward compatibility, which is:
com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle11gDataStoreHelper